# How to determine which platform configuration to use from within a custom Nuget package?

Tags: c#, configuration, nuget

I have a class that I need to put in a nuget package for internal use. This class needs to access some configuration settings but can potentially be installed in a Framework or Core application, so I don't know if it's a web.config, an app.config or an appsettings.json. Doing web searches for this just turns up articles on how to configure nuget (not how to get a nuget to read from the config files). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

If your package targets both .NET Framework and .NET Core, or .NET Standard 2.0 or earlier, and you want to detect the target runtime when you compile the code, you could use a [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) in your source code, e.g.:

```
#if (NETCOREAPP1_0 || NETCOREAPP1_1 || NETCOREAPP2_0 || NETCOREAPP2_1)
    //.NET Core specific code...
#else
    //other...
#endif
```

Comment: That makes sense. so if I understand correctly, I basically would assume DI was used on Core with my custom settings object and on package installation modify the startup.cs, and the else would just use the ConfigurationManager? Am I safe in assuming ConfigurationManager handles whether or not web.config or app.config is being used?

Comment: @shnar: No, you can't safely assuming how the consuming application handles configuration. You can use `ConfigurationManager` in .NET Core and you can use JSON based config files in the .NET Framework. Your package cannot tell.

Comment: Hm, then what's the best way to determine how to read config files? Just look for a web.config? If not found, look for app.confg? If not found, look for appsettings.json?

Comment: There is no "good" way to guess how a consuming application configures things. You can *never* be sure.